# Caret package not available for version 3.4.2

Tags: r, r-caret, cran

I'm trying to install the caret package on R, yet I get an error message saying that package ‘caret’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2). Is there any way around this?

Comment: How did you try to install it?

Comment: The only way I've been taught how - install.packages("caret").

Comment: It's hard to know. Add more details, copy and paste your code. And other messages that come with it.

Comment: I've tried both **install.packages("caret")** and **install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)**, but both return an error message saying that it is unavailable for R version 3.4.2. I'm also using a Mac running OS Sierra 10.12.6 if that helps? I'm still new to R so I just assumed it couldn't be loaded, however I thought I'd at least ask to see if there was a way around it! :)

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: Any reason why you can't upgrade R? Version 3.4.2 is about a year & a half old. Looking at `caret` on CRAN shows right up top: Depends:  R (≥ 3.5.0)

Comment: Oh, I never knew that, I'll try that thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`R CMD build` (via r-devel) added the higher requirement of 3.5.0 with this message:

> Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects: `caret/inst/models/models.RData`